# Is kanban (看板) really the same in Japanese and Chinese?

Tags: kanji, chinese

At my company we use a kanban in our software development process.  I speak Chinese and I know the word in Chinese as 看板 (kànbǎn in pinyin), 看 meaning "look" and 板 meaning "board".  Google tells me the word/idea is originally from Japanese, and also romanized like "kanban".  I don't know much about Japanese but I thought usually kanji are different pronunciations than their sister Chinese characters - is it just a happy accident that the words 看 and 板 mean the same thing and are pronounced similarly in both Japanese and Chinese?

Comment: Do you know about [on- and kun-readings](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/onyomi-kunyomi/)? Many words sound similar across Chinese, Korean and Japanese. For example, compare [图书馆](https://forvo.com/search/%E5%9B%BE%E4%B9%A6%E9%A6%86/), [도서관](https://forvo.com/search/%EB%8F%84%EC%84%9C%EA%B4%80/ko/) and [図書館](https://forvo.com/word/%E5%9B%B3%E6%9B%B8%E9%A4%A8/).

Comment: As a side note, when people say "kanban board" it makes my eye twitch

Comment: @Evelyn why? I had never heard of "kanban board" in English, but looking it up, it appears that "kanban" in English is a process management concept and not a physical object, and so "kanban board" distinguishes that concept from the physical object. Seems perfectly reasonable considering the fact that it's a borrowed word.

Comment: Additionally, it appears that かんばんボード exists as a term in Japanese too, presumably imported after the English term developed, though I don't know how well known it is.

Comment: @Leebo Interesting. In my work, "kanban" usually only refers to the board.  I guess it makes sense to say kanban board, it just sounds strange to my ears because on a Chinese software development team, we just called it the 看板. 板 is board so you wouldn't say 看板板 lol.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They just look identical in romanizations. A Japanese person and a Chinese person might understand each other with their native readings, but the real pronunciations have non-negligible differences. Chinese pinyin final *n* is always [n], where Japanese final *n* (as the transcription of ん) is called [moraic nasal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Moraic_nasal) that changes into diverse sounds according to what comes next.

In short, they would respectively sound like:

- Chinese (Mandarin): *kànbǎn* [[kʰan˥˩.p(b)an˨˩˦]] (AmE approx. *can-ban*)
- Japanese: かんばん *kanban* [[kʰɐmbɐɴ]] (AmE approx. *come-bun(gh)*)

As you may know, 看板 is not a Chinese Chinese word, merely a transliteration of the Japanese word meaning "signboard", in the *kanban* system context (ironically, the word is rarely written in kanji in Japanese as for this specific sense) or anime words like 看板娘.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129763/discussion-on-answer-by-broccoli-facemask-is-kanban--really-the-same-in-japa).